# Sequence Limit: $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{n\,x^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

If $-1<x<1$ show that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{n\,x^n} = 0$. I don't have idea. I only prove that $n\,x^n$ is decreasing.

Comment: What methods do you know for finding the limit of a sequence?

Comment: more basic possible.

Comment: Are you able to show that if $|r|<1$, then $r^n \to 0$?

Comment: It's not true that $n x^n$ is decreasing, although it is true that $|n x^n|$ is decreasing for large enough $n$.

Comment: Your acceptation rate converges to zero faster than any other sequence I've ever met...perhaps you'd want to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the series $\sum n x^n$. The ratio test shows that this series converges when $|x|<1$. Hence in this case the sequence of terms must converge to zero.

Comment: But the series test is just the same for sequences. In fact, if $\lim\;\left| \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|<1$ then $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: @Ihf, I like your answer but in order to be able to use it I think you must put $\,n|x|^n\,$, as the ratio series is for positive series. Anyway, +1

Comment: @DonAntonio, but if a series converges absolutely, then it converges. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) for this version of the ratio test.

Comment: Oh, I *know* that, @Ihf, but the ratio test is appliable *only* to positive series, that's all. My point is that, since $\,-1<x<1\,$, the test cannot be applied to the series *as it is*. Of course, once you take $\,|nx^n|\,$ and prove convergence, you have absolute conv. and thus conv.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $|x| < r < 1$, show that $|(n+1) x^{n+1}| < r\, |n x^n|$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x=0$ we're done. 
Otherwise, we can show absolute convergence using [l'Hôpital's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}|n x^n|
&=& \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{|x|^{-n}} \\
&=& \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{d}{dn} n}{\frac{d}{dn} |x|^{-n}} \\
&=& \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{-|x|^{-n}\log |x|} \\
&=& \lim_{n\to\infty} -\frac{|x|^n}{\log |x|} \\
&=& 0.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: I don't think this is strictly correct for $x<0$. You differentiate with respect to $n$, treating it as a continuous variable. But for $x<0$, the quantity $x^n$ is not necessarily real for $n \not \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @JamesFennell: Thanks, James. I believe you are right.

Answer (score 1):

It's not restrictive to assume $x\ne0$, so $0<|x|<1$. Set $1/\sqrt{|x|}=1+y$, so $y>0$; by Bernoulli’s inequality,
$$
(1+y)^n>1+ny
$$
so
$$
|x|^n<\frac{1}{((1+y)^n)^2}<\frac{1}{(1+ny)^2}
$$
Therefore
$$
|nx^n|<\frac{n}{(1+ny)^2}
$$

Note that a similar technique proves that, when $|x|<1$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n^kx^n=0
$$
for every $k>0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $-1<x<1$ then $x=\dfrac{1}{r}$, with $|r|>1$. For example:

$$1>0.1=\frac{1}{10}$$
$$1>0.25=\frac{1}{4}$$
$$1>0.\overline 3 =\frac{1}{3}$$

Then, we can write your sequence as

$$a_n=\frac{n}{r^n}$$

Can you try and see what would happen to $a_n$ for large $n$?

Say $r=2$. Then what would $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{2^n}$$ be? Can you try and generalize?

Also note that for positive $r$ $$a_{n+1}=\frac{n+1}{r^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{r}\frac{n}{r^n}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{1}{r^n}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{r}a_n+\frac{1}{r}\frac 1 n a_n<\frac{1}{r}a_n+\frac{1}{r}a_n=\frac{2}{r}a_n$$

Comment: Where you wrote, in your first line, "...for $\,r>1\,$" , it must be, I believe, "...for $\,r>1\,\,\,or\,\,\,r<-1\,$

Comment: @DonAntonio That should have read $|r|>1$. Fixing...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that one could use the monotonicity of the functions of $n$ in order to justify taking the continuous derivative with respect to $n$ in the l'Hopital argument above (by oen). This would still only work for x nonnegative (by what James mentioned). But then, couldn't one argue that, because
$|nx^n| = |ny^n|$ for positive integers $n$ and for constants $x$ and $y$ (where $x=-y$ and $y$ is positive), that $\lim_{n\to\infty}|nx^n| = \lim_{n\to\infty}|ny^n| = \lim_{n\to\infty}ny^n = 0$. (The second to last equality is valid because $ny^n >0$ and the last equality is the limit whose value is given by the l'Hopital argument.) Could one then say that since $\lim_{n\to\infty}|nx^n| = 0$ that $\lim_{n\to\infty}nx^n = 0$? (-1 < x < 0) This seems fine to me, but let me know what you think.