# Sum of a series - 5

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can anyone simplify this series,

$$S= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n(n-1)}{2^{2n-1}}$$ into a fraction?

Is there a closed form solution for this?

This seems to the answer for one other problem that I am working on?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let $\displaystyle S=\sum_{r=0}^nr(r-1)a^r=\sum_{r=2}^nr(r-1)a^r  $

$\displaystyle\implies a\cdot S=\sum_{r=2}^nr(r-1)a^{r+1}=\sum_{r=3}^{n+1}(r-1)(r-2)a^r $

$\displaystyle\implies S(1-a)=2a^2+\sum_{r=3}^n2(r-1)a^r-n(n-1)a^{n+1}$
$\displaystyle S(1-a)=2a^2-n(n-1)a^{n+1}+2a\sum_{r=3}^n(r-1)a^{r-1}$

Again let $\displaystyle T=\sum_{r=3}^n(r-1)a^{r-1}$

$\displaystyle T-T\cdot a=?$

Can you recognize the Geometric Series?

Now for $|a|<1,$ use [Sequence Limit: $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{n\,x^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173061/sequence-limit-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-inftyn-xn) or [How to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} n x^{n} = 0 $ when $0<x<1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197522/how-to-prove-that-lim-n-to-infty-n-xn-0-when-0x1)

Can you prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}n(n-1)a^n=0$ for $|a|<1?$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Using [Infinite Geometric Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series) $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n=\frac1{1-a}$$ for $|a|<1$

Differentiate  w.r.t $a$  to find $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty na^{n-1}=\frac1{(1-a)^2}$$ (See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series))

Again, differentiate w.r.t $a$

Now, $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n(n-1)}{2^{2n-1}}=2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)\left(\frac14\right)^n$$

Comment: what is a in this?

Comment: I did not downvote it, somebody did and I do not know why they downvoted it

Comment: Could you help me further?

Comment: @satishramanathan, do you know differentiation?

Comment: @Downvoter, Wish I know the mistake here?

Comment: It is coming out $\frac{4}{(1-a)^3}$ where a = 1/4, after evaluating the derivatives I get 128/27, would that be right

Comment: @satishramanathan, http://goo.gl/eUj8O5