# To prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}nz^{n+1} = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I came across with the following limit in a complex analysis course and I'm not sure how to prove it by definition.
$\lim_{n\to\infty} n z^{n+1}$ where $|z|<1$

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you if you don't provide any context or any idea of what it is you have difficulties with.

Comment: Try it in polar form.

Comment: To avoid rapid close votes, check out our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on how to [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}nz^{n+1} = 0$. Let's rewrite $z$ in a ploar form $z = r (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$, where $r = |z| < 1$. Then,
$
|nz^{n+1} - 0| = |nz^{n+1}| = n r^{n+1} |\cos \theta + i \sin \theta|^{n+1} = n r^{n+1}.
$

Now, we rewrite $r = \frac{1}{R + 1}$ for some $R>0$. Note that
$r^{n+1} = \frac{1}{(R + 1)^{n+1}} < \frac{1}{nR + \frac{(n-1)n}{2}R^2}$,
since
$(R + 1)^{n+1} = \sum_{i=0}^{n+1}\binom{n}{i}R^i > \binom{n}{1}R + \binom{n}{2}R^2$.

Thus, $|nz^{n+1} - 0| < \frac{1}{R + \frac{(n-1)}{2}R^2} < \epsilon$ for
$\frac{2}{R^2}(\frac{1}{\epsilon} - 1) + 1 < n_0$.

Comment: Please do not provide answers to posts that lack context and are below the quality standards of  this site. You are just rewarding bad behavior, which only encourages it and makes the site worse and worse by telling folks to go ahead and post bad questions.

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it. Moreover, it was a (multi)[duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/173066/386889) and the ratio test is much more efficient.

Comment: I can't comment on the original post since my reputation is less than 50.
Note also what you mention as a duplicate does not include a proof "by definition".

Comment: Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).